# Running my program through cron causes permission failures

Tags: c, linux

I'm calling a c program using crontab.

If I call the program directly, everything is fine.
If the program is called by cron, my .log files can't be opened.

the program is in a directory

/stuff1/stuff2/stuff3/program

all pathnames in the program are absolute
just to make sure, I chmod 777'd everything in stuff3

EDIT:
The line from crontab is

```
0 * * * * /stuff1/stuff2/stuff3/program
```

EDIT2:

Issue isn't with cron, if I run it like this

```
cd /
/stuff1/stuff2/stuff3/program
```

it fails

if I run it like this:

```
cd /stuff1/stuff2/stuff3/program
program
```

everything is peachy.
What does linux change that could affect my program when run in those two different ways?

Comment: You're likely looking at a permissions/user environment/working directory issue.  Hard to tell from the information given exactly what though.

Comment: We need more specific information; the exact line from your crontab would be a good start. BTW `chmod 777` is overkill; typically 755 for executables and directories and 644 for other files is good enough. Also, this isn't really a programming question; I'm going to flag it for migration to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Linux probably doesn't change a thing. Does `program` write files to the current directory?

Comment: The program writes a single logfile `ofstream file("/stuff1/stuff2/stuff3/update.log", ios::out | ios::app);`

Comment: What's the output of `which program` ?

Comment: The last snippet you posted probably doesn't run your program. It's runs a `program` from `${PATH}`. Your would be invoked through `./program`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the program I was forking was attempting to write to ./
This caused permission failures as cron doesn't run the program from the directory it is in, rather it runs it from some other directory that I didn't have write permissions in.

Answer (score 0):

This'll probably help you get to the bottom of it, since you know at least some C:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/debugging-with-syscall-tracers.html